# How to use System.IdentityModel in own client-server application

Tags: c#, wcf-security, .net-3.0

I've got a simple client-server application based on TcpClient/TcpListener and SslStream. Clients can authenticate themselves to the server using a X509Certificate or by sending a user name and password after the SslStream has been established.

WCF makes use of the **System.IdentityModel** namespace for authentication purposes, but [apparently](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CommentView.aspx?guid=85585fae-f04f-4de9-8207-631a0b228b06) that can be used in arbitrary applications--which sounds interesting. Information on how to do this is sparse though (or my Google foo is weak today).

So, my question is: **What do I need to do to integrate System.IdentityModel with my application?** I'm not sure if I need all that ClaimSet stuff, but it would be nice if users could log in just using their Windows account or any other provided authentication mechanism. (Unfortunately I can't just switch to WCF but have to use the custom protocol, although I can make some changes to it if necessary.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My Google foo was indeed weak. The answer is right behind the link in my question. So here are a couple of links to [this blog](http://leastprivilege.com/category/identitymodel/) in case somebody has the same question eventually.

First, you should try to understand "that claim set stuff":

- [Claims](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/19/using-identitymodel-claims/)
- [Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/23/using-identitymodel-claim-sets/)
- [Inspecting Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/23/using-identitymodel-inspecting-claim-sets/)
- [Windows and X509Certificate Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/24/using-identitymodel-windows-and-x509certificate-claim-sets/)
- [Typical Operations on Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/24/using-identitymodel-typical-operations-on-claim-sets/)

Then, you need to know where claim sets come from:

- [Authorization Policies, Context and Claims Transformation](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/29/using-identitymodel-authorization-policies-context-and-claims-transformation/)
- [Claims Transformation in WCF](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/03/04/using-identitymodel-claims-transformation-in-wcf/)
- [Authorization Context and Claims Transformation outside of WCF](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/03/04/using-identitymodel-authorization-context-and-claims-transformation-outside-of-wcf/)

Armed with this knowledge, it actually becomes quite simple.

If I understand it correctly, the basic workflow would be something like this:

1. Client creates a `SecurityToken` using a `SecurityTokenProvider`
2. Client serializes the `SecurityToken` using a `SecurityTokenSerializer`
3. Server deserializes the `SecurityToken` using a `SecurityTokenSerializer`
4. Server creates `IAuthorizationPolicy`s using a `SecurityTokenAuthenticator`
5. Server creates `AuthorizationContext` from `IAuthorizationPolicy`s
6. Done

Example:

```
// Create the SecurityTokenProvider
var p = new UserNameSecurityTokenProvider("username", "password");

// Get the SecurityToken from the SecurityTokenProvider
var t = p.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)) as UserNameSecurityToken;

// ... transmit SecurityToken to server ...

// Create the SecurityTokenAuthenticator
var a = new CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator(
    UserNamePasswordValidator.None);

// Create IAuthorizationPolicies from SecurityToken
var i = a.ValidateToken(t);

// Create AuthorizationContext from IAuthorizationPolicies
var c = AuthorizationContext.CreateDefaultAuthorizationContext(i);
ShowClaims(c.ClaimSets);
```

For `X509SecurityToken`s use a `X509SecurityTokenProvider`/`Authenticator`. For `WindowsSecurityToken`s there's a `WindowsSecurityTokenAuthenticator` but not a provider; instead, use the `WindowsSecurityToken` constructor:

```
var t = new WindowsSecurityToken(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```

This works quite well. The only thing I omitted so far above is the token serialization. There is a `SecurityTokenSerializer` class which has one implementation in the .NET framework: the `WSSecurityTokenSerializer` class which comes with WCF.

Serializing `UserNameSecurityToken`s and `X509SecurityToken`s works like a charm (haven't tried deserialization), but `WindowsSecurityToken`s are apparently not supported by the serializer. This leaves me with the two authentication methods that I already have (certificates and username/password) and, as I didn't want that `AuthorizationContext` anyway, I'll stick with what I have :)

Comment: In case anybody is interested, I'm not sure the SecurityToken should be created on the client side and transmitted to a server. For X.509 security it makes much more sense to initiate a SslStream with the server and create the X509SecurityToken from the server certificate, for Windows security the WindowsSecurityToken can be created from the negotiateStream.RemoteIdentity if a NegotiateStream is used. For username/password security, of course, the username and password will need to be transmitted.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment to the existing solution, but I'd like to post the new URLs to the blogs listed in the solution, since those don't work anymore. If someone can change this to a comment, I'd be much obliged.

- [Claims](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/19/using-identitymodel-claims/%20Claims)
- [Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/23/using-identitymodel-claim-sets/)
- [Inspecting Claim Sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/23/using-identitymodel-inspecting-claim-sets/)
- [Windows and X509 Certificate claim sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/24/using-identitymodel-windows-and-x509certificate-claim-sets/)
- [Typical operations on claim sets](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/24/using-identitymodel-typical-operations-on-claim-sets/)
- [Authorization policies, context and claims transformation](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/02/29/using-identitymodel-authorization-policies-context-and-claims-transformation/)
- [Claims transformation in WCF](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/03/04/using-identitymodel-claims-transformation-in-wcf/)
- [Authorization Context and Claims Transformation outside of WCF](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/03/04/using-identitymodel-authorization-context-and-claims-transformation-outside-of-wcf/)

Comment: I've edited @dtb's answer above to reflect the fixed links. It should show up as soon as it's peer reviewed. Thanks!

Comment: As of September 2016 some of the links are broken